# Java ScriptEngine fails for 'long' addition?

Tags: java, scriptengine

I'm using the ScriptEngine to perform calculations specified in a String. I tried a simple program as below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    Float f;
    try {
        f = new Float(engine.eval("1340984972921+7200000").toString());
        System.out.println(f.longValue()+"");
    } catch (Exception e){}
  }
```

This gives the output of 1340992126976 but the correct answer is 1340992172921

This seems to work for reasonably large integers but fails for long values. I want them as long values because they are timestamps and I want to use them as such. Any ideas on what could make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the data type from `Float` to `Double`. I think it's a precision problem.

Comment: FYI, `Float` is 32-bit and Double is `64-bit`, floating point number.

Comment: Darn the Float! Works like magic with Double! Thank you so much!